# Prove that if two norms on V have the same unit ball, then the norms are equal.

Tags: real-analysis

Note: This homework question does NOT mean 'equivalent', but equal.

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be two norms with the same unit ball. So, $$B(1,0)= \{v \in V:p_1(v) \leq 1 \}= \{v \in V:p_2(v) \leq 1\}$$

I don't know how to take it from there. Any hints and/or help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $p_1(v)< p_2(v) $ for some $v$. Let $w=v/p_1(v) $. Then $p_1 (w)=1$, so $w\in B(0,1)$. But $p_2 (w)> 1$, and this implies that $w\not\in B(0,1) $, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$. Then
$$
\rho_1\left(\frac{v}{\rho_1(v)}\right)=\frac{1}{\rho_1(v)}\rho_1(v)=1
$$
so 
$$
\rho_2\left(\frac{v}{\rho_1(v)}\right)=1
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{1}{\rho_1(v)}\rho_2(v)=1
$$
Hence $\rho_1(v)=\rho_2(v)$.